# Does azure use static ip on a standard 1 app service plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, static-ip-address

Have one app service plan (standard 1 pricing tier) with only one web app.  From what I understand I have a static ip based on this configuration / price.  So when I do an nslookup on my web site and get an ip back, that ip is static correct?  Just needed verification.  TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So when I do an nslookup on my web site and get an ip back, that ip is static correct? Just needed verification

Every Azure Web App have 1 external IP address and multi outbound addresses.  What you saw from nslookup is external IP address.

The external IP address(Inbound address) is used for domain binding(A record binding). If you want to binding your custom domain, please use external IP address. You could find the external IP address from Azure portal. Web App->Custom Domains tab.

From [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name), we know

*If you delete and recreate your app, or change from a higher pricing tier back to the Shared tier, your app's external IP address may change.* Otherwise, the external IP address won't be changed.

Traffic come from your web app will use one of the outbound addresses as IP address. There is no agreement of when the outbound IP address will change or not. They will not change from 1 day to the next, nor is there any plan or real need to change them.

> will there be some type of notification from azure when the outbounds do change?

There is no official document which pointed it out. I found following words from MSDN forum. Hope it will be helpful for you.

1. *It becomes necessary for Azure infrastructure to increase the number of outbound IP addresses. In that case the existing IP addresses will be preserved but there will be some new ones. So far there hasn't been a need to increase number of IP addresses and if there ever be the need for that there will be an early notice about it.*
2. *The Web App gets relocated to a different scale unit. Prior to that the subscription owner gets an email notification one month in advance.*

From: [Static outbound IP addresses for Azure Web Apps?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fca449e5-ce46-4b63-bbac-7f01d13debd1/static-outbound-ip-addresses-for-azure-web-apps?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Comment: Thanks @Amor.  This is exactly what I was looking for. Just curious, if the outbound IPs do happen to change for the web app, will there be some type of notification from azure when the outbounds do change?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you are assigned 4 external IP addresses, so at the very least there are 4 ip addresses you need to consider static, but from what I can tell they are subject to change (that's how it previously was, I'm not sure if it holds now).

Also, remember that those are shared, so whitelisting those is potentially dangerous.

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41.  Where do I find the list of these 4 external ips on the azure portal?

Comment: go to properties, its there @LosMorales

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41.  Found it (was looking at app service plan by accident).  Do you know on what condition(s) these ip addresses change?  Personally I don't mind them changing from time to time given that there is some upfront notice or knowing the conditions for the change to prepare ahead of time.